# I am running a dual boot, but now have 13 different options to choose from

Tags: linux, windows-7, partitioning

I am running a dual boot of Windows 7 and Linux Mint. Now on start-up, I have:

- Linux Mint 13 Maya (13) (on /dev/sda6) - Displayed 5 times
- Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon 64-bit, 3.2.0.23-generic displayed 3 times
- Memory Test (memtest86+)
- Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)
- Dell Utility Partition (on /dev/sda1)

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have GRUB2, since I've seen and have ended up with this situation commonly with it.

You did not do anything wrong. It is just that when you did software or package updates in `Linux Mint` it looks like it has brought in the newer kernels and the older kernels did not get removed. You could look at how to remove or purge the older kernels.

It is not a problem to have these extra kernels lying around (other than consuming an extra few megabytes of disk space).

Answer (score 0):

Each time you upgrade your kernel, another entry will be added. To remove them, purge any non-latest versions of kernel and run update-grub (or whatever the equivalent for Linux Cinnamon is)